# How many times have I written to my USB drive?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, usb-storage

It is possible to determine how many times I've written to my USB 2.0 thumb drive? Are there any third party tools I could use to determine this?

Comment: This isn't really something the firmware would likely expose it serves very little purpose to the end user.

Comment: This information typically is exposed as part of the S.M.A.R.T. data, very easy to read from IDE, SATA, and SCSI drives, may or may not be available for a USB drive.  Try a tool like CrystalDiskInfo.